# only in terminal error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex

code snippet:

```
for line in f:
    x = re.search(r'<([^,]+),\s?([^>]+)>', line)
    x,y = int(x.group(1)), float(x.group(2))
```

**file.txt** sample

```
<185, 5.00>
<231, 5.00>
<292, 5.00>
```

The problem here is that when run on IDLE it turns out fine for the remaining of the code 
but when executed on terminal, it returns the following error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I know what that means but why did it work in the python IDLE in the first place ??

Comment: Have you done anything yourself to try and debug this? Are you printing out what `line` is in both environments? Are you examining what `x` is in both environments?

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example that will reproduce this? Assuming a minimal addition of `f = open("file.txt")` to your code, it works for me in Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe in the shell you have a different file.txt or so, that has an empty line at the end! In any case it is perfectly valid that none is returned from re.search and you ought to handle it properly, say: `if x is None: continue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only cause I can think of is that your file `f` does not have to be the same in both environments, so in IDLE `re.search` matches every line, while in terminal it iterates over something, but that's not that file and so at least 1 line does not match regexp. `x` is then `None` and trying to dot access `group` of it raises exception.

In general, you can't assume that `re.search` will match every line. I'd do:

```
result = re.search('....', line)
if result:
     result.group()
     ...
```

Another issue: you're recompiling regexp on every line. That's mighty inefficient. Better use `regex = re.compile(....)` before loop and then use `regex`'s methods (same as `re.search`, `re.findall`, etc) inside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

When `re.search` cannot find a match it returns `None`. You need to check for that eventuality. Your code does not check and then attempts to access an attribute `group` that the `None` object does not have.

It is safe to assume that `re.search` operates correctly. Therefore the remaining conclusions are that either:

1. The text contained in `line` is not what you expect it to be, or
2. Your regex is incorrect.

Your next step is to do some debugging. Look at the values in `line`. If they are not what you expect, option 1 above is the likely cause. If these values are as you expect then it would appear that option 2 is the explanation.